# SQL Server Data tool is not getting installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-data-tools

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 shell integrated on my machine and after that trying to install SQL Server Data Tools 2012; SSDT not getting displayed on Visual Studio but it shows up in `Add/Remove Programs` tool and seems installed.

Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the vs 2012 version of ssdt?

Comment: yes.In Add/Remove Programs it seems installed